# Practical and Tasty choices for a high protein diet

Tags: diet, protein, high-protein

I'm looking for some practical yet tasty solutions for a high protein diet. I like food that has intense flavour.

In a bid for this question not to be closed, can you please post a bit of information on the nutrional value of the food.

For example, Egg whites:
11g of protein per 100g

Comment: A trick to make the food more tasty is to use a lot of spices. 

Add flavor with no calories. :-)

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious. Eat lots of meat. Throw in some fish for variety.

Comment: You might be surprised that you can get more protein from fish.  A 7oz filet of Tilapia can have up to 40g protein just by itself.  Calories are pretty low and it is fairly anti-inflammatory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to put together a day with about 1400 calories and 148g protein.  I have added a little bit of intensity to most of the meals.  I love chobani greek yogurt and edamame the way they are, so I didn't add intensity to them.  Also, 1400 calories is probably too low for you, so go ahead and adjust this to reach your calorie goal.  *Please note, I am not advocating 148g of protein as healthy*.

**Breakfast** - 360 calories, 44g protein

Cereal, milk, blueberries - Special K Protein Plus (3/4 cup) + 1/2 Cup Fat Free Milk - 140 calories, 18g protein.  *Intensity* - 1/2 cup blueberries - 42 calories, 0g protein.

Scrambled eggs - 1 large egg - 70 calories, 6g protein. 3/8 cup of egg white - 44 calories, 10g protein.  Ham 2oz - 60 calories, 10g protein.  *Intensity* - 2 cloves of garlic. Scramble

**Brunch** - 160 calories, 13g protein.

Greek yogurt - Chobani greek yogurt - 160 calories, 13g protein.

**Lunch** - 520 calories, 46g protein

Tuna fish sandwich - 2 slices of whole grain bread - 220 calories, 10g protein. 4oz of Tuna - 100 calories, 22 protein.  2 tbsp fat free mayo - 20 calories, 0g protein.  *Intensity* - 1 tbsp pickle relish - 20 calories, 0g protein.

Pinto beans - 1/2 cup pinto beans - 130 calories, 8g protein. *Intensity* - 1 tbsp Hot & Sweet mustard - 30 calories, 6g protein

**Snack #1** 110 calories, protein 9g

Edamame - 1/2 cup edamame - 110 calories, Protein 9g

**Supper** - 240 calories, 36g protein

Chicken breast - 4 oz chicken breast - 190 calories, 36g protein. *Intensity* - 2 tbsp hot salsa - 50 calories, 0g protein

**Ideas for adding Fat to the diet**

- Replace Skim Milk with 2% or whole milk
- Along with your scrambled eggs, stir fry chopped onions, peppers, and mushrooms in a tbsp of olive oil.
- As another snack, make your favorite salad.  Add cheese and balsamic vinaigrette.
- Eat your favorite natural peanut butter with crackers, a rice cake, or make a peanut butter sandwich.
- Eat a handful of your favorite nuts.

Comment: That's awesome mate!

Comment: Agree 1400 calories is probably too low. Good amount of protein for that calorie level, but you gotta get some fat in there! I don't see enough for this to be sustainable...

Comment: Agree, but you could possibly make it sustainable with the extra calories you have.  I have added five ideas that would easily increase your fat.  And the saturated fat would be low.

Comment: Horray for eggs, edamame, tuna, and chicken (although I'm a dark-meat type myself). Most people don't know about edamame but it's a great source of lean protein (plus dietary fiber and omega-3 fatty acids). If it contained all of the essential amino acids it would be nature's perfect protein.